# Flash Action script 2 - Kliment random script

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am using the red flash ecard on this site http://www.flashmint.com/wp/2010/12/free-flash-christmas-e-cards-for-everyone/#more-2206 to send out to some client, but I wanna change some of the things like the colour so I have loaded it up changed the colour and re published it, however the twinkle lights don't flash at random anymore, they flash all together, this code that seems to control this is

```
var randRun = new kliment.utils.RandomRun(this, 100, true)
```

Now what is this kliment and do I need it somewhere on my root folder, even though when I download the original and run it from my computer the twinkles work fine. I suppose this is a hard question to answer but though I would try.

Thanks
in advance,

Ian

Answer (score 0):

If problem is really in that class, then you should have it in you project folder - *kliment/utils/RandomRun.as*
If it is not there you could download it at - https://code.google.com/p/code-library-kliment/source/browse/trunk/as2/kliment